# Symfony 3 Doctrine - How to Generate Entities from database with underscore_separate naming convention

Tags: doctrine, naming-conventions, symfony

I have table like *product_id -> name, description, price* I want all columns naming conventions to be underscore_separate

I have try to set *naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore* in *config.yml* 
then generate entities with command like: *php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml*

But it's still being CamelCase

So what I should do to change columns name's naming conventions to be underscore_separate when I generating entities?